# Javascript to PHP, correct json format

Tags: javascript, php, json, object

I am having trouble with converting JSON string to PHP Object/Array. I googled a lot, watched youtube tutorials, but still missing something.

JAVA SCRIPT:

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'save.php');
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var json_string = '{"name":"Bandage","picture":"129"}';
xhr.send("item=" + json_string);
```

PHP:

```
$item = json_decode($_POST['item']);
```

$item is then NULL

Any idea? If I dont use json_decode function, I get the ctring posted correctly.. What is wrong, how is the format supposed to look like so PHP json_decode can parse it to object or array? I also tried with /json header , stripslashes in PHP, no result.. 
Thanks!

Comment: Try **JSON.stringify()** to converts a value to JSON notation.

Comment: Can you post what var_dump($_POST['item']); returns on php

Comment: your `var json_string` is a valid json...  But are you really getting `$_POST` data... post data like @juank said.

Comment: Names and values sent as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` can require [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) to be valid -- `xhr.send("item=" + encodeURIComponent(json_string));`. This is regardless of whether they're first encoded as JSON or otherwise.

Comment: Check the [`json_last_error_msg()`](http://php.net/json_last_error_msg) after `$item = json_decode($_POST['item']);` for any details. Post those here.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for late reply, trouble with new internet connection. 
Thanks for the posts, I got it working like this:

SCRIPT:

```
var xhr;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
}
else {
    throw new Error("Ajax is not supported by this browser");
}
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
            //document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        }
    }
}

var postitem = '{"name":"Bandage","picture":"129"}'; // working

xhr.open('POST', 'save.php');
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send("item=" + postitem);
```

PHP:

// get the q parameter from URL

$item = trim($_POST['item']);

```
$obj = json_decode($item);
```

echo $obj->name;